# how to retrieve specific field from oracle db then pass it to jsp?

Tags: java, database, class, jsp

I want to pass "name" form f.jsp to class s.java then inside s.java class i need to retrieve the age of received name from database and send the age to another jsp file..
anyone have idea to write code for that?

f.jsp

```
String name = (String) request.getAttribute("myname"); //get name from servlet 
Student s= new Student();
String grade = s.getStudentGrade(name);
```

s.java

```
 public String getStudentGrade(String name)
{
   Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement s = null;
    String g;
    try {
        con = DBconn.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT grade FROM REGISTRATION where Username="+name;
        s = con.prepareStatement(query);
        s.setString(1,""+this.getgrade());
        ResultSet result = s.executeQuery();
        while( result.next())
        {
         g=result.getString("grade");

        }
          return g;


    } 
    catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); return null; }
}
```

when I run this code always return null..can any one help me
hint: my Db is 
Username  password  grade
Ali       1234      3
I need when getStudentGraed() receive name, then retrieve the grade of that name

Comment: First you have to share your ideas with us ...

Comment: s.java is a Servlet ???

Comment: @MadushanPerera no its java class

Comment: I added an answer .. please check

Answer (score 0):

For PreparedStatement you have to use wildcard ? instead of concatenating with query..

1:- You have to extend HttpServlet.

2:- You have to define the @WebServlet annotation or you have to declare your servlet in web.xml file.

```
@WebServlet("/getGrade")  
public class getStudentGrade extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement s = null;
    String g;
    try {
       con = DBconn.getConnection();
       String query = "SELECT grade FROM REGISTRATION where Username=?";
       s = con.prepareStatement(query);
       s.setString(1, name);
       ResultSet result = s.executeQuery();
       while( result.next()){
         g=result.getString("grade");
       }
       req.setAttribute("grade",g);
       req.getRequestDispatcher(your Jsp Page path).forward(req,resp);

 }

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req,resp);
}
```

}

In JSP page you can get it like

```
     <p>Grade : ${grade}</p>
```

Comment: i don't want to retrieve grade value in servlet ...but i need to retrieve it in class then use return value in jsp

Answer (score 0):

To my understand you need to access java class from jsp. I think below example will help you.

```
public class Student {

private String name;

public String getGrade() {
    String grade = null;

    con = DBconn.getConnection();
    String query = "SELECT grade FROM REGISTRATION where Username=?";
    s = con.prepareStatement(query);
    s.setString(1,this.name);
    ResultSet result = s.executeQuery();
    while( result.next()){
     grade=result.getString("grade");}
    return grade;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

**In your servlet :**

```
   <%
     package_name.Student c = new package_name.Student();
        c.setName("John");
        request.setAttribute("attribute", c);

    %>
```

**Access inside jsp :**

```
 ${requestScope["attribute"].grade}
```

Comment: the student name is already received from servlet... my need is define class to return the grade of the received name

Comment: K . So you can receive the grade by `${requestScope["attribute"].grade}`.